# How do I set every players Exp based on a scoreboard of Kills in 1.16 snapshots

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it to where when say, a player kills another player they will gain 1 EXP whole level for every kill. I've already made the /scoreboard for player kills and  just need to make the EXP thing, but I can't figure out how after going through a lot of youtube tutorials.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/experience

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is to have players gain 1 level of EXP for every time they kill another player. Doing this will use one repeating command block and one chain command block, as well as a scoreboard objective with the criteria `minecraft.killed:minecraft.player` (for the sake of the commands, I'll say this objective is named "kills". If you named it something else, just replace that with whatever you named yours.) This objective will NOT reflect the number of kills a player has total once you have done this, so if you want to do that, I would recommend making another objective with the same criteria, and a different name.

First you'll set a repeating command block set to 'Always Active'. Put the following command into it:

```
xp add @a[scores={kills=1}] 1 levels
```

This will add 1 level of XP to every player that has a score of 1 in the "kills" objective.

Next set a chain command block coming from the previous one, and set it to 'Conditional' and 'Always Active'. Put the following command into it:

```
scoreboard players reset @a[scores={kills=1}] kills
```

This command will only run if the previous command successfully ran, and will set everyone's score to 0 who has a 1 in the "kills" objective. This is done so that once they get another kill on a player it will go back up to 1, giving them another level, and then resetting them back to 0.